# Session timed out because the browser was idle for 90 seconds in Browserstack

Tags: python, selenium, browserstack

I am running Automated Selenium tests in Browserstack my tests sometimes fail due to below error

> Session timed out because the browser was idle for 90 seconds

In Browserstack settings, they have mentioned

```
IDLE TIMEOUT
If a session is idle for more than 90 seconds, the session is stopped, changing the session status to TIMEOUT on the dashboard.
```

But I cannot find  a way to change this. Can anyone tell me how can I change this timeout?

Comment: @AlaEddineJEBALI `IDLE TIMEOUT` in browserstack is universal constant and it is not in our control according to their support team. I changed my code in order to tackle this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change the IDLE Timeout duration for sessions on BrowserStack Automate. If you have a specific use case and need to increase the duration, I'd suggest contacting their support team.

Comment: I cannot find any option in Browserstack automate to change IDLE Timeout.

Answer (score 2):

It should be because you missed to add **driver.quit()** in your test.

> The **driver.quit** statement is required, otherwise the test continues to
>   execute, leading to a timeout.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the value for BROWSERSTACK_IDLE_TIMEOUT by specifying the capability 'browserstack.idleTimeout' in your test scripts as mentioned below

```
**"browserstack.idleTimeout" : "300"**
```

Note: The default value is 90 seconds. The maximum duration that can be specified is 300 seconds.

Alternatively, you can execute dummy commands in the test script to keep the session active such as:

```
thread.sleep(50000);
driver.getTitle();
thread.sleep(50000);
driver.getTitle();
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/error-codes/browserstack-idle-timeout#python

```
capabilities = {
 "browserstack.idleTimeout": "300"
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. Your answer would be much more valuable to us if you added an explanation about what your code does and why it helps the OP